# I want variable fileContent outside but it is saying undefined

Tags: node.js, this, shadowing

I am getting data from a promise, when it is resolved but I couldn't find a way how to use this data, the code will clear more.
further, it is not clear to me that the 'this' in the code is referencing to which object. According to me, it is referencing to the global object.

```
p.then(function(data){this.fileContent = data});
 return res.render('experiments',{pageTitle:'Experiments',user:req.session.email,data:this.fileContent});
```

data will be assigned to this.fileContent but in res.render function when I am using this.fileContent it is saying undefined why is that so

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function, in your example if you debug and see, in you r example the function is binding it own self to this where as arrow function actually DOES NOT bind it’s own this. Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context.

```
p.then((data)=>{this.fileContent = data});
```

or simple you can use a variable outside this scope and assign data to it, like in your code

```
let resp ;
p.then(function (data){resp = data}); // do not use this
// process resp here
```

Comment: can you suggest me any resource where I can read this in deep?

Comment: if worked please accept or upvote question for others reference

Comment: not working, I think I need to mention that this whole code is inside an arrow function.

Comment: then cant you use a outside variable and assign data to it

Comment: I have tried using an outside variable like var fileContent ; p.then((data)=>{
           fileContent = data ;
        });
        console.log(this.fileContent);
        return res.render('experiments',{pageTitle:'Experiments',user :req.session.email,data:fileContent});

Comment: let fileContent;
        p.then((data)=>{
           fileContent = data ;
        });
        console.log(fileContent);

Comment: I used the above code but it is printing undefined on the console.

Comment: Please make sure that you are getting response in p.then, log response inside it

Comment: I am getting response inside that block but when I come outside from that block it is gone .